# JNativeHook registers more keyPresses than wanted during key hold

Tags: java

I am using JNativeHook to listen for key presses. When the key is hold down, say the computer is supposed to type the key 4 times, each JNativeHook method will register a lot more than that.

I tried:

```
public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
 System.out.println("registered key release");
}
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
 System.out.println("registered key press");
}
public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
 System.out.println("registered key type");
}
```

All of these methods will register the wrong amount of key presses while the key is being held down. I don't think this is a glitch of the JNativeHook library, since it is almost the same as Java's KeyListener, except it's global.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user presses a key, keyPressed will be called and then keyTyped will be called, and then finally when the user releases his/her finger from the key, keyReleased is called. Try printing out keyPressed, keyTyped and keyReleased messages rather than typing "registered" everywhere, in order to understand as to what is happening.

Comment: The code I put in is just a sample. In my actual program, I can confirm that all three are registered more times than needed.

Comment: Show the code that you actually wrote so that the problem can be pinned down.

Answer (score 0):

> The code I put in is just a sample. In my actual program, I can confirm that all three are registered more times than needed.

If that is the case, and you are still experiencing a problem, please [report a bug](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/issues?state=open).  The detectable auto repeat failed to enable on your platform for some reason.